# Jwt token vs access token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, access-token

I'm studing IdentityServer4 and I got question. I know that exist jwt token which need for checking token. It checks that token was gotten from trust server. There is access_token which need to authorize in app. How does it work? I get two tokens or jwt contains a access_token as well?

Comment: Please note that a JWT is not IdentityServer4 specific. IdentityServer4 implements a number of OpenID Connect and OAuth2.0 specifications. In order to understand IdentityServer4 it helps to understand the [specifications](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/specs.html).

Comment: In case of IdentityServer the token can contain an Access Token, an Identity Token and a Refresh Token. But this depends on the configuration and the used flow. An alternative of the JWT token is the [reference token](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html).

Comment: I did it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an Auth Server(The server which issues the JWT token), you will received a **JWT Token** aka **Access_Token**. This Auth Server will contains the Secret-Key that can issues an Access-Token.

From a client(Mobile/Web/Console App), you will need to pass this Access_Token in your Request Header to your Resource Server(The server where your resources stored, normally this is your backend server) to request for Resources/Data.

`(e.g : Authorization : Bearer <Access_Token>)`

Upon receives a request from client,in your Resource Server, you will need to have a Validate JWT function that will validate the JWT Token based on a public-key (Security Algorithm : RSA256, HS256).

Reference:
https://medium.com/dev-bits/a-guide-for-adding-jwt-token-based-authentication-to-your-single-page-nodejs-applications-c403f7cf04f4

[**JWT IO Introduction**](https://jwt.io)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. JWT toke is access token or i have to get access token by jwt?

Comment: JWT is a format - generally speaking JWT could be used for an access token or any other token.